# Averiguar alto de una imagen y guardarlo dentro de una variable en javascript

Tags: javascript

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacer en javascript para hallar el alto en pixeles de una imagen del cual no sabemos su tamaño y luego guardarlo en una variable para poder operar con él?

Intenté ya de muchas formas y no pude lograrlo.

Por ejemplo, intenté con:

```
var miVariable= document.getElementById ("id de la imagen").height;
```

Pero me tiraba error en chrome.

Pero sí me dejaba mostrar su valor por la consola de esta manera:

```
console.log (document.getElementById ("id de la imagen").height);
```

Dejo el código javascript y el html por si quieren verlo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="archivo.js">
  </script>
  <script>
  /* Simulamos la ejecución del contenido de "archivo.js" aquí: */
  var vMin = document.getElementById("corazon1").height;  //ACA ES DONDE ME TIRA ERROR
  </script>

  <style>
    .corazonesImg {
      width: 4%;
    }
    
    .contenedorCorazon {
      display: inline;
    }
    
    #vida {
      position: absolute;
      left: 15px;
      top: 15px;
    }
    
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="vida">
    <div class="contenedorCorazon" id="contenedorCorazon1"><img src="corazon.png" class="corazonesImg" id="corazon1" alt=""></div>
    <div class="contenedorCorazon" id="contenedorCorazon2"><img src="corazon.png" class="corazonesImg" id="corazon2" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Exactamente, ¿qué error "te tira" chrome?

Comment: Te falta `.style`  ► `document.getElementById ("id de la imagen").style.height`

Comment: @x3k_js , [`HTMLImageElement.height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) es una propiedad perfectamente válida, por lo que el error podría estar siendo generado por no existir el ID (no haberse generado el DOM del elemento a analizar).

Comment: @OscarGarcia Pensaba que era único del atributo `style`, mea culpa! Gracias por la info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edición tras publicar código javascript y HTML completo:**

Tal y como supuse, el problema lo tienes por tratar de acceder a un elemento por su `id` cuando aún no ha sido creado.

Tienes varias soluciones. Las ordeno de menor a mayor complejidad o esfuerzo:

- Colocar la etiqueta `<script>` al final del documento HTML.
- Indicar al navegador que ejecute el código javascript tras la carga del documento haciendo uso del [atributo `defer` de la etiqueta `<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer).
- Mover el código dentro de una función que se ejecute [tras la carga del DOM (evento `Window.DOMContentLoaded`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

---

### Mover `<script>` al final

En el siguiente ejemplo ejecuto el código javascript al final del documento, cuando el DOM ha sido generado completamente.

```css
.corazonesImg { width: 4%; }
.contenedorCorazon { display: inline; }
#vida { position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 15px; }
```

```html
<div id="vida">
  <div class="contenedorCorazon" id="contenedorCorazon1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/26/23/58/rose-2892821_960_720.jpg" class="corazonesImg" id="corazon1" alt="Rosa"></div>
</div>

<!-- Colocamos la carga de "archivo.js" al final del documento HTML
  (antes de </html>, por ejemplo) -->
<script src="archivo.js"></script>
<script>
/* Simulamos la ejecución del contenido de "archivo.js" aquí: */
var vMin = document.getElementById("corazon1").height;  //ACA ES DONDE ME TIRA ERROR
console.log('Valor de vMin:', vMin);
</script>
```

---

### Usando el atributo `defer`

Como no disponemos de un servidor para realizar alojamiento de archivos, en el siguiente código simulo el funcionamiento de "defer":

```css
.corazonesImg { width: 4%; }
.contenedorCorazon { display: inline; }
#vida { position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 15px; }
```

```html
<!-- Usamos el atributo "defer" -->
<script src="archivo.js" defer></script>

<div id="vida">
  <div class="contenedorCorazon" id="contenedorCorazon1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/26/23/58/rose-2892821_960_720.jpg" class="corazonesImg" id="corazon1" alt="Rosa"></div>
</div>

<script>
/* Simulamos que la ejecución del contenido de "archivo.js" se hace tras la carga del DOM: */
var vMin = document.getElementById("corazon1").height;  //ACA ES DONDE ME TIRA ERROR
console.log('Valor de vMin:', vMin);
</script>
```

### Esperar al evento `DOMContentLoaded`

Requiere de una reestructuración más compleja del código, pero es la más recomendable:

```css
.corazonesImg { width: 4%; }
.contenedorCorazon { display: inline; }
#vida { position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 15px; }
```

```html
<!-- Podemos seguir haciendo uso de "defer" o "async" -->
<script src="archivo.js"></script>
<script>
/* Ejecutamos el código cuando el DOM haya sido cargado: */
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', evento => {
  var vMin = document.getElementById("corazon1").height;  //ACA ES DONDE ME TIRA ERROR
  console.log('Valor de vMin:', vMin);
});
</script>

<div id="vida">
  <div class="contenedorCorazon" id="contenedorCorazon1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/26/23/58/rose-2892821_960_720.jpg" class="corazonesImg" id="corazon1" alt="Rosa"></div>
</div>
```

---

### Respuesta original

**Siempre que el DOM haya sido generado** (ver comentarios al final de la respuesta), tendrás disponible las siguientes [propiedades de una imagen `<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement):

> - `HTMLImageElement.naturalHeight` <kbd>Read only</kbd>: Devuelve un `unsigned long` que representa el alto intrínseco de la imagen en píxeles CSS, si está disponible, de otro modo, es `0`.
> - `HTMLImageElement.height`: Es un `unsigned long` que refleja el atributo HTML `height`, indica el alto de la imagen en píxeles CSS.
> - [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect): El valor devuelto es un objeto `DOMRect` que es la unión de los rectángulos devueltos por `getClientRects()` para el elemento, es decir, las CSS `border-boxes` asociadas con el elemento.

Un ejemplo de uso podría ser el siguiente:

```js
let mostrar = () => {
  let imagen = document.getElementById("imagen");
  console.log('imagen.height: ', imagen.height);
  console.log('imagen.naturalHeight: ', imagen.naturalHeight);
  let recuadro = imagen.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log('recuadro.bottom - recuadro.top: ', recuadro.bottom - recuadro.top);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar datos</button>
<p><img id="imagen" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/26/23/58/rose-2892821_960_720.jpg" alt="Rosa" width="50%" /></p>
```

Una de las causas que podría generar el problema que apuntas en la pregunta podría ser tratar de acceder al elemento **antes de que el DOM asociado haya sido generado**, pero sin el código completo ni el mensaje de error exacto no podremos descartar esa posibilidad.